# Create drop down menu without ul inside li

Tags: html, css

I want to create a drop down menu but I faced some problem:

Actually I want to create it without making `<ul>` tag inside the `<li>` tag
so the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Coffee</a></li>
      <ul><li><a>Coffee 2</a></li></ul>
    <li><a>Tea</a></li>
    <li><a>Milk</a></li>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

and the css code :

```
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover {
background: #3b3b3b;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #1e7c9a;
}
```

You can see that `Coffee 2` is not dropdown it should be with coffe menu please help me 
without making the `<ul>` tag inside the `<li>`.

jsbin link : http://jsbin.com/evasof/1/edit

Comment: You can't have a `<ul>` as a child of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` only an `<li>` is valid

Comment: .... This is impossible I am afraid, why wont you add the ul into the li as it supposed to? http://jsbin.com/evasof/4/

Comment: how please update jsbin

Comment: @AntarAzri did update it. see prev comment

Comment: so there is no solution ???

Comment: actually i want to make a subject and page in mysql and php

Comment: This is impossible on the basis that it is syntactically invalid to do so, which is bad.  Is there a reason why you don't want to next the UL inside the LI?

Comment: i want to make a subject and page in mysql and php and i cant do it

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What's wrong with nesting a `<ul>` inside a `<li>`?  People are more likely to be able to help you if they know *why* you're trying to accomplish something.

Comment: i cant make a drop down menu by mysql subject and pages for each subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dpdwn"><a>Coffee</a><div><a>Coffe 2</a></div></li>
    <li><a>Tea</a></li>
    <li><a>Milk</a></li>
</ul>
```

extra css:

```
.dpdwn div{
    display: none;
}
.dpdwn:hover div {
    display:block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c24gc/)**

But in my opinion you should use a `ul` inside that `li`.
Here's an example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dpdwn"><a>Coffee</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Coffe 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Tea</a></li>
    <li><a>Milk</a></li>
</ul>
```

That same extra css:

```
    .dpdwn ul{
    display: none;
}
.dpdwn:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy2gt/)**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your HTML structure above, we can see that when we try and validate it at the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) that this structure is INVALID, and not accepted.  You can see this from the provided screenshot below...

[image: Invalid Markup]

Beyond the fact that what you want is invalid markup, CSS-wise it is also impossible to handle the hover state in order to make your sub-menu appear.  There is no selector in the current standard that allows you to select a sister sibling while hovering over a sibling.

My suggestion is to follow how it has been done for ages, what is valid markup, and how it will be for the foreseeable future, and nest the `ul` inside the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Coffee</a>
      <ol><a>Coffe 2</a></ol></li>
    <li><a>Tea</a></li>
    <li><a>Milk</a></li>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
you can use <ol> tag within <li> tag see above example
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dl` and `dt` and style them accordingly but I'm afraid at that point you're just trading one tag for another. As w/ the other answers, why are you trying to avoid using `ul` and `li`. Creating dropdown menus is something that there tags are very good at.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Foo</dt>
    <dt>Bar</dt>
</dl>
```